Angular ngModelChange data inconsistency
Facing an issue where a key has same value in another object in an array of objects. When ngModelChange is trigerred for 2nd one the data obtained in the ts file is of first one.
I have data as follows:
[
  {
    id: 'main_1'
    name: 'Sample', 
    subCategory: [
      {
        id: 'sub_2'
        name: 'View',
        permissions: [
          {name: 'sample 1', description: 'description 1'}
        ],
        isPresent: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'main_3'
    name: 'Sample 2', 
    subCategory: [
      {
        id: 'sub_4'
        name: 'View',
        permissions: [
          {name: 'sample 2', description: 'description 2'}
        ],
        isPresent: true
      }
    ]
  }
]

My parent component fetches this data from store and passes to a child component.
<div *ngFor="let item of (data|async);trackBy: trackByFn;">
  <app-child [childData]="item"></app-child>
</div>

In my child component I loop over the object and display the ui.
<div *ngFor="let sub of childData.subCategory; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFnMain;">
  <div>
    {{sub.name}}
  </div>

  <div>
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      [ngModel]="sub.isPresent
      (ngModelChange)="updateData($event, sub)"
    >
    <label [for]="sub.name + i"></label>
  </div>
</div>

The name key value in sub is 'View' Which is same for two of the objects. While a checkbox/toggle is trigerred for the second item in the array the value received in updateData is of the first one:
{
    name: 'View',
    permissions: [
      {name: 'sample 1', description: 'description 1'}
    ],
    isPresent: true
  }

I modified the trackBy to as follows, still no change occurred. Only time it worked was when i changed name value in one of the objects to some other value.
trackByFnMain(index: number, subCategory: any): string {
  return subCategory.id;
}

Note: Made the id, name unique. As there were similar names like name: 'View' simply name + index took wrong toggle. Adding one more unique identified fixed the issue.

In parent component, what is your trackByFn?

@rajniszp I have updated the data. I use id in trackBy as shown in the piece of code.

I am not talking about trackBy: trackByFnMain; in your child component, but about trackBy: trackByFn; in your parent component. You did not provide your implementation. An editable code snippet would be helpful

Same implementation, there is a id field which is used for trackBy

Make sure  you added id and name to the input fields.
<div *ngFor="let sub of childData.subCategory; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFnMain;">
  <div>
    {{sub.name}}
  </div>

  <div>
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      [id]="sub.name + i"
      [name]="sub.name + i"
      [ngModel]="sub.isPresent
      (ngModelChange)="updateData($event, sub)"
    >
    <label [for]="sub.name + i"></label>
  </div>
</div>


Your input was helpful, added unique values to id & name and got it to work. Just that sub.name + i alone wouldn't suffice, had to add one more unique identifier. In my case added one from matMenu reference

@Akhilpaul please update my answer with the proper fix to help someone else in the future, or post a new answer
